# Helper for tag html a

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, tags, helper

is there any helper in asp.net MVC3

```
<a href="www.google.com">Go to Google </a>
```

?

Not for an action but to a static link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is, but I'm not sure why you would want one. You'd actually end up with more code:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Go to Google</a>

<%: Html.Link("http://www.google.com/", "Go to Google") %>

@Html.Link("http://www.google.com/", "Go to Google")
```

**Update:** If you want to create a `Link()` helper like that above, you would use an extension method:

```
 public static class LinkExtensions
 {
    public static MvcHtmlString Link(this HtmlHelper helper, string href, string text)
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("a");
        builder.MergeAttribute("href", href);
        builder.SetInnerText(text);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
 }
```

Comment: There is no method 'Link' in class'html'.

I want to make more standard, after all textbox, actions, all have dropbox Usage helpers. So it lacks the (static link)

Comment: I had to declare the first parameter as `this HtmlHelper<dynamic>` but it worked otherwise.

Comment: In that case, you'll have more flexibility if you make the method generic: `Link<T>(this HtmlHelper<T> helper, ...`