# How to create my custom helper in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, extension-methods, html-helper, helper

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400571/helper-for-tag-html-a) question here on the forum for static link helper, but I got no answers yet. So I decided to create my own helper.

I'm trying to create a helper for a static link

```
<a href='xx'>yy</a>
```

but is displaying the HTML code.

**Using:**

```
<div>
@Html.Link("www.google.com", "Google")
</div>
```

**Result:**

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
```

**See my class:**

```
public static class BindHelper
{
    public static TagBuilder Link(this HtmlHelper helper, string targetUrl, string text)
    {
        TagBuilder imglink = new TagBuilder("a");
        imglink.MergeAttribute("href", targetUrl);
        imglink.InnerHtml = text;
        return imglink;
    }
}
```

How to create my own helper? 
Already researched on several sites and some extended the method returns a string in the other class TagBuilder but both ways it displays the HTML code on page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return an `MvcHtmlString`. That is what MVC does internally. It (somewhat)  implements [`IHtmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihtmlstring.aspx) which tells the HTML encoder not to reencode the value.

Also add your namespace to the build configuration section of the `web.config`.

Comment: but in cases where the project is not to MVC?

Comment: In the example it is pointing to http://localhost:3400/Riderman.Sample.AMSD/Views/Home/www.google.com